# how to include advanced text edit tool

Tags: html

[image]just a quick question, is there a way I can embed adevance text edit tool like the above picture shows in the html or php page? your help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is generally known as a What You See Is What You Get editor or WYSIWYG.

There are a number of options on the market, all I know of are in JavaScript.

For my projects I use [CKEditor](http://www.ckeditor.com) personally, greatly due to the integration of CKFinder for file uploads. CKEditor is easy to integrate and get running quickly in a number of environments. Their developer and user docs are also quite good.

However a nice and simple to use in-line HTML5 editor is [Aloha Editor](http://www.aloha-editor.org). My preference however is to CKEditor greatly due to the fact it is easier in my opinion than Aloha and it has many more options.

Simply look for "web based WYSIWYG editor" in Google and you will find a whole heap more to choose from!

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention something, CKEditor is Open Source making it fantastic if you need "deeper" integration into your own code. I'm not sure about Aloha however. With this I have integrated our own permissions system into CKEditor allowing per-user permissions to functions rather than having to write a selection of more rigid configuration files or having to write 1 configuration file per user.

Comment: I agree, CKEditor is really easy to setup, very flexible, and has a ton of documentation and support on the forums and SO.

Answer (score 0):

I often used [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/).

Base usage is very simple... [check it out](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php)!